# How to switch ruby bundler from rvm to asdf?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm, asdf

I am using rvm and I needed to switch to asdf, I installed ruby 2.3.1 using asdf but when I execute `which bundler` I get this:

```
/Users/ali/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/bundler
```

how can I switch the bundler from rvm to asdf ?

Comment: you can update the `PATH` env to make the `asdf` directory before `rvm` directory which may resolve the issue in case you want to keep both, if you want to `rvm` then just run `rvm implode` command which may also resolve the issue since you will only have `asdf` version manager.